# behind proxy doing npm install

Tags: npm, proxy, great-firewall-of-china

```
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^0.14.8 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.1" from react-element-to-jsx-string@14.3.4
npm WARN   node_modules/@storybook/react/node_modules/react-element-to-jsx-string
npm WARN     react-element-to-jsx-string@"^14.3.4" from @storybook/react@6.5.10
npm WARN     node_modules/@storybook/react
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-element-to-jsx-string@14.3.4
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.1.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm WARN   103 more (@expensify/react-native-web, @storybook/addon-a11y, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^0.14.8 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.1" from react-element-to-jsx-string@14.3.4
npm WARN node_modules/@storybook/react/node_modules/react-element-to-jsx-string
npm WARN   react-element-to-jsx-string@"^14.3.4" from @storybook/react@6.5.10
npm WARN   node_modules/@storybook/react
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^0.14.8 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.1" from react-element-to-jsx-string@14.3.4
npm WARN   node_modules/@storybook/react/node_modules/react-element-to-jsx-string
npm WARN     react-element-to-jsx-string@"^14.3.4" from @storybook/react@6.5.10
npm WARN     node_modules/@storybook/react
npm WARN skipping integrity check for git dependency ssh://git@github.com/Expensify/react-native-image-manipulator.git 
npm WARN skipping integrity check for git dependency ssh://git@github.com/Expensify/react-native-image-size.git 
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network aborted
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

The majority of the package seems to be installed fine, but only this (or maybe some later ones that are not encountered yet) has this behind proxy problem.

I am using a proxy in order go pass the chinese Internet restriction, fot git fetch, brew, it all works fine (which without the proxy I can't access github from the terminal)